# Determine the determinant

Tags: determinant

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & -\omega & \omega^2 \\
    -\omega & \omega^2 & 1 \\
    \omega^2 & 1 & -\omega \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$
 I can solve the question by doing $c_1'=c_1+c_3\omega~~$.this simply gives the answer $-4$.but when I am trying to go on another procedure like ,if I perform 
$r_1'=r_1\omega+r_2~~$ then I am getting the answer $-4\omega$ which was not same as the previous procedure.please let me know my mistake.
Here,\omega  is a root of $\sqrt[3]{1}\text{  and is} =\dfrac{1}{2}(-1+i \sqrt{3})$ .And $c_n,r_n$ represent $n_{th}$ row or column.
Thank you.

Comment: Please declare $\omega$. All those letters $c_1, c_3, c_1'; r_1, r_2,r_1'$ are never defined, the question has no point of reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & -\omega & \omega^2 \\
    -\omega & \omega^2 & 1 \\
    \omega^2 & 1 & -\omega \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$
$$
=\dfrac{1}{\omega}\begin{vmatrix}
    0 & 0 & \omega^3+1 \\
    -\omega & \omega^2 & 1 \\
    \omega^2 & 1 & -\omega \\
    \end{vmatrix}[r_1'=\omega r_{1}+r_2]
$$
$$=\dfrac{(\omega^3+1)}{\omega}
\begin{vmatrix}
    \
    -\omega & \omega^2  \\
    \omega^2 & 1  \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$
$$=\dfrac{(1+1)}{\omega}(-\omega (1+\omega^3))$$
$$=\dfrac{-4\omega}{\omega}=-4$$

Answer (score 3):

$r_1' = r_1 \omega + r_2$ does not preserve the determinant.  What you're actually doing are two elementary operations : $r_1'' = \omega r_1$ which **multiplies the determinant** by $\omega$ and then $r_1' = r_1'' + r_2$ which preserve the determinant.

So you when you do $r_1' = r_1 \omega + r_2$, you must divide by $\omega$ to counterbalance the fact that this operation scaled the determinant by $\omega$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a more systematic way:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\omega & \omega^2 \\
-\omega & \omega^2 & 1 \\
\omega^2 & 1 & -\omega
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\omega & \omega^2 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&&\begin{aligned}R_2&\gets R_2+\omega R_1\\ R_3 &\gets R_3-\omega^2R_1\end{aligned}
\\[6px]
\color{red}{(-1)}\qquad&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\omega & \omega^2 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_2\leftrightarrow R_3
\end{align}
(assuming $\omega^3=1$). Then the determinant is $(-1)\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 2$. The factor $-1$ is due to the row swapping operation.

Note that an operation such as
$$
R_1\gets \omega R_1+R_2
$$
(in your notation $r_1'=\omega r_1+r_2$) ***does*** change the determinant, multiplying it by $\omega$. And indeed, you find $-4\omega$, which should be divided by $\omega$.

An operation such as
$$
R_i\gets aR_i+bR_j
$$
(with $a\ne0$ and $i\ne j$) is admissible in this context, but remember it multiplies the determinant by $a$. Similarly for columns.

In my elimination I always used $a=1$.